# Rotation Slider in Python Fails

Tags: python, math, rotation, vpython

**Goal:**

My goal is to rotate the white line as you change the slider value. But it doesn't work! Please assist. Image: [Rotation Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghbrA.png)

**Effort:**

Things I've tried:

- Drawing white line as a curve and rotating the curve with `rotate` method
- Drawing white line as an arrow and rotating arrow with `rotate` method
- Establishing a `frame` f and appending white line to frame and rotating the frame
- Using a `for loop` to continually update the angle of the line.

Please assist.

**Code**: [Rotation Slider](https://www.glowscript.org/#/user/RBari/folder/ABridgefromMaxwelltoEinstein/program/AxesRotation/edit)

**Relevant Lines:**

```
c = curve(pos = [vector(-10,0,0),vector(10,0,0)], radius = 0.3)

def setspeed(s):
    wt.text = '{:1.0f}'.format(s.value)
    
sl = slider(min=0, max=360, step = 10, value = 45, bind=setspeed)

wt = wtext(text='{:1.2f}'.format(sl.value))

c.rotate(angle=sl.value, axis = vector(0,0,1), origin = vector(0,0,0))
```

Comment: I'm no expert with GlowScript, however, I would recommend checking that the `c.rotate()` function is being called continuously and that `sl.value` is being updated.

Comment: I'll comment that for GlowScrippt VPython questions it's better to post to the GlowScript VPython forum, where there are many more GlowScript VPython users who will see your question than if you post to stackoverflow:

https://groups.google.com/g/glowscript-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that the rotate function expects angles in radians, not degrees, so you would say angle=radians(sl.value).